# How to solve error "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-unit-test, angular-jest

I am developing unit tests in an Angular 12 app with the help of [Jest testing framework](https://jestjs.io/). Now there is a console error *"Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'"* within child component after test run.

By the way, the data which is checked in `*ngIf` condition is received via `@Input()`

Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="month-name" *ngIf="name && year">
    {{ name.toUpperCase() }}
    <span class="year">{{ year }}</span>
</span>
```

This is the TypeScript code:

```
export class MonthNameComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string = '';
  @Input() year: string = '';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Finally, this is what the test file looks like:

```
    describe('MonthNameComponent', () => {
      let component: MonthNameComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<MonthNameComponent>;
    
      beforeEach(async () => {
         await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [CommonModule],
         declarations: [MonthNameComponent],
         providers: [],
         schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
       }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MonthNameComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

**NOTE:**

I have read multiple recommendations regarding this error and did following things:

1. Checked existence of `CommonModule` for a lazy loaded module that contains this component
2. Imported `CommonModule`into the `.spec` file of component
3. Included the component in `TestBed` providers
4. Re-run application (several times).
5. Added `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` into `schema` array

However, the error message still appears.

Comment: why you have two separate beforeEach blocks? can you please try to combine their code in one?

Comment: just tried, still the same. (I put the updated test into the question)

Comment: Can you please try to add `BrowserModule ` to your imports?

Comment: shall I import it into tests?

Comment: Yes, ` imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule],`

Comment: Done, but still the same

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan Did you ever get this to work?  Having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding the child component in declaration array of parent spec component, it should look like that :

```
describe('ParentNameComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentNameComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentNameComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
     await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [CommonModule],
     // add your child component here
     declarations: [ParentNameComponent, MonthNameComponent],
     providers: [],
   }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentNameComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```